# -->>Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\romit\Desktop\FlutterSoft\projects\basic_app\android\build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\romit\Desktop\FlutterSoft\projects\basic_app\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\romit.gradle\caches\6.7.1\scripts\4hhqko2lgng4etjv4i11vmj58).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

NOTE: I have already updated the gradle. Also tried solving it by using gradlew clean and gradlew build.

**DOES ANYONE HAVE SOLUTION FOR THIS?**

///build.gradle snippets

[Code LINE -1-27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJRFJ.png)

[Remaining Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1JtJ.png)

Comment: Can you post the contents of your build.gradle file? It appears to not like something on line 26.

Comment: yes please, do share your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major Version 60 is for `Java 16` - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout.

As far as I know Android does not support this java version at all. Also it seems Android Studio does only support Java 7 (full) and Java 8 (partial) - see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.

> Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0 and later support all Java 7 language
> features and a subset of Java 8 language features that vary by
> platform version. When building your app using Android Gradle plugin
> 4.0.0 and higher, you can use a number of Java 8 language APIs without requiring a minimum API level for your app.

I am using Eclipse most time, but I think the settings can be done as described at
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#jdk

Comment: I tried this but in my case there is no such option of embedded jdk under gradle!!

Comment: I deleted jdk-16 and reinstalled android studio and flutter and finally it worked for me!!

Comment: @PatelRomit: If the answer solved your problem, please mark it  as useful and the question  as solved.